Film (maybe a parody) involving cyclops aliens and eating a cookie
Help me find the name of this movie.
It looked like a very old movie, it was a parody maybe.  There's a guy with a mustache. He’s in space I think, and there’s cyclops aliens.  There’s a female and male in a different costume. The male is collecting junk and he gives mustache-guy something that looks like a giant brown cookie. He takes a nibble and he says it’s good enough and starts floating around.

When did you watch it? Did you watch it in the theaters? On VHS? Laserdisc? DVD? Streaming service? Was it in English? Did it look like it had been dubbed? How were the special effects? CG? Practical? Were the protagonists caucasian?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Sounds like something from a Cheech and Chong movie, but their only UFO scene I know of does not really match: https://youtu.be/K_uo9-hMCF0?t=311

The movie is Gentlemen Broncos (2009) and matches exactly the description provided. The scene described (cookie, floating/flying) can be found on YouTube and appears to be quite campy. Strange coincidence, as I found this particular bit of cinematic absurdity just yesterday.

Someone posted it as a meme that made it to the front page of Reddit the other day. I think many people had this question.

Omg how did you find it with my terrible description?? haha I randomly saw it on tiktok, and then it got deleted before I was able to show my bf. I thought maybe I imagined it haha! Thank you so much!!

It's been trending on TikTok as well.
